# Do requests sessions end when the program is killed?

Tags: python, session, cookies, python-requests

Is there anyway to pickup on a previous session when starting a python program?

I've set session as a global variable so that it can be accessed across any method that needs it. However, I'm guessing when I start the program again the session variable is reset.

Is there a way to come back to a previous session when starting the program?

```
session = requests.Session()

def auth():
    session = self.session
    url = 'this url has auth'
    session.post(url, data=data)
    # Now authentcated so lets grab the data
    call_data(sessions)

def call_data(session)
    url = 'this url has the data'
    session.post(url, data=data)

def check_data()
    url = 'this url does a specific call on data elements'
    self.session.post(url, data=data)
```

When I load up my program a second time I will only want to use check_data method, I'd prefer to not require an auth every time I start the program, or perhaps I'm just curious to see if it can be done ;)

**EDIT** 
I've updated my solution with the accepted answer.

```
def auth():
    session = self.session
    session.cookies = LWPCookieJar("cookies.txt")

    url = 'this url has auth'
    session.post(url, data=data)
    # Now authentcated so lets grab the data
    call_data(sessions)

    session.cookies.save() #Save auth cookie

def some_other_method():
    if not cookie:
        session.cookies.load()

    # do stuff now that we're authed
```

Code obviously don't show proper accessor for other methods, but the idea works fine. 
Would be interested to know if this is the only way to remain authed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sessions are tracked in http via cookies. You can save them between program restart by storing in a [`http.cookiejar.LWPCookieJar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#http.cookiejar.LWPCookieJar)

At the beginning of your program you have to set the `cookieJar` to this [`FileCookieJar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#http.cookiejar.FileCookieJar) and load the existing cookies if any

```
import requests
from http.cookiejar import LWPCookieJar
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies = LWPCookieJar("storage.jar")
session.cookies.load()
```

before closing your program you have to to save them to the file

```
session.cookies.save()
```

Note that by default it has the same behavior than browser that it **doesn't save** session cookies which are not set to persistent to your browser across restart if you want a different behavior, just precise it to [`save()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#http.cookiejar.FileCookieJar.save) method by setting `ignore_discard` argument to `False` like this

```
session.cookies.save(ignore_discard=False)
```

Comment: Nice response- that explains it well. I believe this is what I was inadvertently doing when I was using curl instead of requests, as I have a cookies.txt file saved when I auth. This same file would be accessed to auth the next call even if the program was closed.
I will try this in the morning and more than likely accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what kind of session you try to establish. Django? Flask? Something different?
Be aware also that there seems to be a misspelling of call_data(sessions) where only session (without s) is defined.

Comment: The code listed is quite literally the session I use, I'm not sure on what Django or Flask is in regard to sessions specifically.
Also, nice find, however, I wrote this as a bit of a skeleton of my actual code so the spelling mistake you have pointed out is not present in the real thing :)